# Does there exist an OpenStack API with its implementation being JClouds?

Tags: openstack, jclouds

I am trying to find if there exists an OpenStack REST API with its implementation being JClouds. I am willing to pay for someone to produce such a thing as an open source project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftProxy offers an OpenStack Swift implementation backed by Apache jclouds:

https://github.com/bouncestorage/swiftproxy

It back ends onto multiple jclouds storage backends including the local file system and many object stores.